# RedirectMatch 301 shows a get parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My problem is htacccess , I have the following:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /tag/what\+is\+abc$ /344/what-is-abc.htm
```

but resulting url is:

```
http://www.abc.com/388/what-is-abc?q=what-is-abc
```

Why am I getting the q parameter?  I am trying to not display $_GET variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
RedirectMatch 301 /tag/what\+is\+abc$ /344/what-is-abc.htm?
```

The last '?' overrides the querystring.

Comment: i do not want query string. only redirect to /344/what-is-abc.htm

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `RedirectMatch`? As far as I can tell from your question a simple `Redirect` would suffice.

```
Redirect 301 /tag/what\+is\+abc$ /344/what-is-abc.htm
```